# Java WebApp Security frameworks

Tags: java, security

I'm working on a implementation of a webapp in Java, where there will be limitations on some roles shall only be able to read data and some to update. All roles shall not have access to all pages.

I've looked at Apache Shiro together with JSP/Javascrip/CSS.

Are there any other alternatives for this?
Or is this the best choice?

//Henrik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider Spring Security, formerly known as Acegi.

http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/

Seems it's a bit more mainstream:

http://www.indeed.com/jobtrends?q=Apache++Shiro%2C+Spring+Security&l=

Comment: It seems to contain all attributes needed, but is it portable for non-sping projects?

Comment: Yes. It works independently from the rest of the application.